# How do display multiple lines in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How do I display all of this information here in just one dialog? Every time I run the file different dialog boxes appears, I really need them to appear in just one dialog box with all the information.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Name:"+a1,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your age:"+age,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Birth year:"+a3,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Height:"+H,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Weight:"+W,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your BMI:"+BMI,"Output",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `HTML` tags:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><br>First line.<br>Second line.</html>");
```

Or you can pass an array of objects:

> An array of objects is interpreted as a series of messages (one per
>   object) arranged in a vertical stack

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a `JPanel` with proper layout, as you want to place the components to be placed, and then add this `JPanel` to the `JOptionPane` to display the message.

A small example to help you understand the logic thingy :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JOptionPaneExample {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int birthYear;

    public JOptionPaneExample() {
        name = "Myself";
        age = 19;
        birthYear = 1994;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, getPanel(), "Output : ",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        JLabel nameLabel = getLabel("Your Name : " + name);
        JLabel ageLabel = getLabel("Your Age : " + age);
        JLabel yearLabel = getLabel("Your Birth Year : " + birthYear);
        panel.add(nameLabel);
        panel.add(ageLabel);
        panel.add(yearLabel);

        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel getLabel(String title) {
        return new JLabel(title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JOptionPaneExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: optionpaneexample]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Javadoc for JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), specifically the message part at the top. If you pass in an array of Object, its elements will be put in a vertical stack in the dialog.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                              new Object[]{"line 1","line 2","line 3","line 4"},
                              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just enter this instead of all those lines:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Name: " + a1 +"\n Your age: " + age +"\n Your Birth year: "+ a3 +
    "\n Your Height: " + H +"\n Your Weight: "+ W +"\n Your BMI: "+ BMI);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks